# Flutter: Getting info from firestore

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So I have tried many methods posted here on Stackoverflow and I have not had the luck in successfully getting data from firestore and printing it

I am trying to get a book, by it's title from the firestore.

Created a service to get the doc

```
class ConstantHabit
{

   getConstantHabit(String requestTitle)
{
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('HabitList')
    .where('title', isEqualTo: requestTitle)
    .get();

}
```

}

Initializing it on my page

```
  void initState(){
super.initState();
ConstantBook()
    .getConstantBook('test')
    .then((QuerySnapshot docs)

{
  print('test');
  if(docs.docs.isNotEmpty)
    {
      getBookFlag=true;
      constantBook = docs.docs[0].data;
      print('test');
      print(constantBook);
    }
```

And then trying to just put it on the screen

```
Text(constantBook['title']),
```

However, whatever I try I always get

The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

My items are pretty simple as well
[image]

What can I do to output it successfully?

Comment: You need to update `constantBook` inside of `setState`.